# Images do not appear with vue-router history mode when I build the app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using vue-router in story mode.
When I run the `npm run build` command, I get the dist folder, and I'm using `XAMMP` to serve the files in local, I added the settings suggested by the site for the apache server, but the images do not load, the console appears `(404 Not Found)` for each image I am serving.

Route where the images are:
`dist / static / images / image.png`

I do not know what to change so that the images can be seen.
How can i solve this?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the way you are serving static files, not vue js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `dist/index.html` edit the path of your css and js files. Remove the first slash

Answer (score 4):

you can add base tag in your index.html eg:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made

Answer (score 2):

better solution:
you can add base tag in your index.html eg:

```
<base href="<%= BASE_URL %>" />
```

the default *BASE_URL* is `'/'` but you can change **baseUrl** in `vue.config.js` or `webpack.config` file , if you need to.